# 仮想環境とフォルダ共有した上での Play Framework 2.0 の自動ビルドについて

Tags: java, vagrant, playframework

`Vagrantfile` に `config.vm.synced_folder` でAPIを仮想環境とホストで共有しています。

- 仮想環境: VirtualBox + Vagrant
- API: Play Framework 2.0 + Java

仮想環境で `activator run` を走らせて、ホストのAPIに変更を加えると自動ビルドが走るようにしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

ホストのAPIをいじる → 仮想環境で自動ビルドする方法についてご教授頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分も同じ問題で困ったことがありましたが、synced_folderの設定をRsyncにすることで解決しました。

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

おそらくファイル変更をフックできない事が原因なので、Rsyncでならば問題ないと思います

Answer (score 1):

手元では試せてないですが `run` ではなく `~run` でどうでしょう？

- [Using sbt features](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole#Using-sbt-features)
- [Auto-reloading with Play framework on a network filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299300/auto-reloading-with-play-framework-on-a-network-filesystem) - stackoverflow.com